# Resize photo taken by camera to fit screen

Tags: java, android

I'm attempting to make an app that displays the photo after its taken.
The issue is I can't seem to scale the bitmap with the same aspect ratio to the screen.

I've tried imageView.setScaleType(ScaleType.FIT_XY); but it doesn't keep the ratio.
Nor does any of the Android:Scale.

What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
Bitmap.createScaledBitmap (Bitmap src, int dstWidth, int dstHeight, boolean filter)
```

Here is the snippet! 
hope this will help you

```
 public static Bitmap createScaledBitmap(String path, float scale, boolean filtering){
    Bitmap src = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(path);
    int width = (int)( src.getWidth() * scale + 0.5f);
    int height = (int)( src.getHeight() * scale + 0.5f);
    return Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(src, width, height, filtering);
  }
```

Take a look at documentation also
[Create Scaled Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createScaledBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20int,%20int,%20boolean%29)